# Unit testing with Jasmine, expect().toBeVisible()

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I need to detect the CSS display value after a click event has been executed. I am sure it is user error, but I cannot get Jasmine.js to report if an elements visibility has been changed after the click.

Here is the codepen link: http://codepen.io/nicholasabrams/pen/dPYoJr

Here is the code itself: (this is obviously not the actual case that it is being used in however it is a very simplified version that recreates the issue I am having currently)

```
$('#button1').on('click', function(){

  $(this).append('<button id="#button2">!!!!!</button>');

});
```

Here is the test itself:

```
describe("button#1 click test", function(){

   beforeEach(function(){
     $('#button1').click();
   });

   it("Should inject a new button with #button2 as the id", function(){
      expect($('#button2')).toBeVisible();
   });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

At first - in your pen you should add external script for [jasmine-jquery](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery/1.5.3/lib/jasmine-jquery.js). Next, button in a button, it's illegal according to [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element) `Phrasing content, but there must be no interactive content descendant.` Jasmine is just fine, try to append to parent:

```
$('#button1').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().append('<button id="#button2">!!!!!</button>');
});
```

Working pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxvGja?editors=101

Comment: The fact that it is illegal has no bearing on the test failing. That was not the point. Second thank you for the help however the pen you posted has a failing test as well.. I am not seeing how taking the append out of the button fixed anything. Let me know if I am wrong. I will supply a more 'standards compliant' version in a second

Comment: Tested on FF33.1 it works just fine. The code in you pen is failing mainly because "TypeError: expect(...).toBeVisible is not a function" - you didn't include jasmine-jquery

Comment: http://codepen.io/nicholasabrams/pen/GgpoPP this is the same issue, with jasmine-jquery loaded. I must be missing something stupid here because I have used jasmine for this before except I typically set up a fixture as opposed to this way where I am testing actual DOM interaction.